# Initialize managedContect in AppDelegate for other Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I want to initialize managedObject, but I always get this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

The ViewController I want to use Core Data / managedObject is not my launching ViewController, but an other one (PortfolioVC) I am accessing through my launching ViewController.

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DatabaseController {
    private let modelName: String

    init(modelName: String) {
        self.modelName = modelName
    }

    lazy var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        return self.storeContainer.viewContext
    }()

    private lazy var storeContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: self.modelName)
        container.loadPersistentStores { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        guard managedContext.hasChanges else { return }

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    lazy var coreDataStack = DatabaseController(modelName: "Portfolio")

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        guard let navController = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController,
            let viewController = navController.topViewController as? PortfolioVC else {
                return true
        }
        viewController.managedContext = coreDataStack.managedContext
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }


}
```

This is the code in PortfolioVC:

import UIKit
import CoreData

```
class PortfolioVC: UIViewController {


    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var namePortfolio: NamePortfolio?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableViewPortfolio.dataSource = self

        let standardPortfolio = "Watchlist"
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NamePortfolio> = NamePortfolio.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(NamePortfolio.name), standardPortfolio)

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) // here I get the error (managedContext = nil)
            if results.count > 0 {
                // Portfolio already created
                namePortfolio = results.first

            } else {
                // no Portfolio
                namePortfolio = NamePortfolio(context: managedContext)
                namePortfolio?.name = standardPortfolio
                try managedContext.save()
            }
        }  catch let error as NSError {

            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    }
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: How do you access the PortfolioVC from the “launching view controller”?

Comment: With a UIButton like this: "@IBAction func portfolio(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToPortfolio", sender: self)
    }" Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` runs, the PortfolioVC has not yet been added to the navigation controller stack (or even instantiated), so the guard fails.  There are two ways to get the managedContext to the PortfolioVC:

a) pass it to your launching view controller in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, then pass it from there to the PortfolioVC using prepareForSegue.  You will need to add a managedContext property to your launching VC, even though you only need it to pass on to the Portfolio VC.

b) in PortfolioVC, get a reference to the AppDelegate and then get the managedContext from there.

```
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        managedContext = appDelegate.coreDataStack.managedContext
    }
```

Opinions vary as to which of these is the better design pattern.